Windows 10 "forgets" external USB drives and then rediscovers them
I have a Windows 10 system with quite a few external USB drives connected. Over the past several months, it has started to "forget" that a drives is connected, only to "rediscover" the drive a second or two later.  his can happen while the drive is in use, which is obviously a problem. I recently replaced the USB 3.0 expansion card I was using with a new USB 3.2 card and I also replaced the USB 3.0 external/powered hub with a new USB 3.2 model.
Unfortunately, while it appears to be much less frequent, the problem still occurs.
Are there any settings, deep down inside Windows that I can adjust to help prevent this from happening? I'm thinking that perhaps I could change a setting to make Windows more tolerant of whatever it is that is triggering the "drive no longer connected" condition.
Oh, I should mention that all the external drives are in 4-bay Mediasonic Probox units, and usually only one drive from a box containing 3 or 4 drives is lost and recovered. I'm asking Mediasonic Probox support, but I don't actually expect them to be helpful.

How many drives exactly? While USB is designed for a hundred or so devices, often you will reach the resource limits of a controller, well before that number is reached. Storage devices are especially require more resources than say a mouse or keyboard. If this is a USB resource problem there isn’t a setting, as the disconnect, is a side effect and actually protection, against the entire controller crashing or crashing the NT kernel

Also, for whatever reason, I notice some USB hubs disconnect and reconnect, even with just a mouse as the only device. One hub was made much more stable after fastening it and cables to a piece of aluminum serving to keep things physically stable, and as both ground plane (connected to USB shell) and heat sink. Admittedly, I cannot state why, in particular that worked, but I hear fewer disconnect/connect tones, now.

There are 10 USB drives in three 4-bay enclosures (4-3-3).  I think I'm starting to notice that all of the failures are coming from drives in a particular enclosure, so I'm going to swap it out and see if that fixes my problem.  FWIW, for backups, I connect one additional USB drive (at a time) to backup each of the media drives in turn.  So at most, I have 11 USB drives (and two internal SATA drives), but when I have 11, I'm sitting there and haven't seen the issue while backing up ... at least not yet.  Thanks for the ideas, though, they help.
